# What is the best way to check if the user is new in firebase google sign in with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add some extra features after new user login with a google login in Flutter.so I need to know if a user is new or not . if the user is new then I want to add some user information. other wise navigate to another page.

So how can I check If the User is new or not?

Answer (score 2):

The [`User` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) has a `metadata` property, which has two properties: `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime`. When those are no more than a few milliseconds apart, the user was just created. If they're further apart, the user was created in a previous session.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseAuth User contains this data in metadata prop. I used the following chunk of code. You can change the number of seconds if you want.

```
bool isNewUser(User user) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime cTime = user.metadata.creationTime;
  int longAgo = 15; // to check account creation under last 15 seconds
  return now.difference(cTime).inSeconds > longAgo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can not reply in the comment,
but i want to clarify  `Ayyaz meo's` answer.

since you gave the function name `isNewUser`, it means it will be new user if return `true`

but your function said that if the creation time was > 15 second ago, then return true.

i think it has to be '<`

```dart
bool isNewUser(User user) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime cTime = user.metadata.creationTime;
  int longAgo = 15; // to check account creation under last 15 seconds
  return now.difference(cTime).inSeconds < longAgo;
}
```