# Is it guaranteed that userMetaData.creationTime and lastSignInTime are equal on first time login in Firebae?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to check if user logging in for the first time or not in Firebase authentication. I do not wish to add another custom variable to keep things simple, so I want to rely on the user metadata returned: `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime`

In their API reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata.md#usermetadata_interface there is no indication whether those two values are exactly the same the first time. So can anyone confirm this? can I rely on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly there **may** be a slight offset between the values, so it's best to check if they're within 100ms (or something equally reasonable) of each other.

Also see:

- [What is the best way to check if the user is new in firebase google sign in with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609117/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-the-user-is-new-in-firebase-google-sign-in-with)

Comment: True, I found instances with milliseconds apart. Unreliable. But I found another way, it's the new getAdditionalUserInfo() function  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getadditionaluserinfo